# How to turn MacBook Air 2015 on if the power button is broken and I don't have tools to remove battery?

Tags: macbook-pro, power, startup

The power button on my macbook air 2015 is not functional and I don't have the correct screwdriver to open the back up and take out the battery. Is it possible to turn the laptop on without having to open the back up?

Comment: Have you tried using one of those Apple USB keyboards that have a power switch?

Comment: no the laptop is off right now though

Comment: Pretty sure it works on iMacs. Might be worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

No. You will want to keep it from discharging enough once you power it on if you can't repair the hardware switch.